# How to truncate values after 6th decimal in Azure Data Explorer kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

round() or bin() doesn't work. I want 0.0833349999 to be 0.083334. So basically anything beyond 6 decimals should be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`round()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/roundfunction) or the [`bin()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction)

for example:

`print input = 0.0833349999 | extend output = round(input, 6)` => `0.083335`

`print input = 0.0833349999 | extend output = bin(input, 0.000001)` => `0.083334`

Comment: No, this does not work for me. The result here is  0.083335, but I want 0.083334

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Here you can use [bin_at()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binatfunction?source=recommendations) and [round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/roundfunction) function together to get desired result:

```
print i = 0.0833349999
|extend o = bin_at(i, 0.000001,2)
|extend result = round(o, 6)
```

Output:

[image]

Here `result` contains **0.083334**

[image]